# Indent block in Sublime text

Tags: html, ide, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Let say I have this block of code:

```
Line 1
  Line 2
    Line 3
  Line 4
Line 5
```

I want to move carret to `Line 2` and hit shortcut key to indent both `Line 2` and `Line 3` but **not** `Line 4` and `Line 5`. Is there a way to do this? Instead of hitting Ctrl+] in each line OR having to select whole block before Ctrl+] when you indeed want to indent the whole block?

Comment: You're just asking how to tab and detab easily?

Comment: Yes. Basically one step of indentation the block. Assuming the code was properly indented before